# R survival package plotting multiple event plots with same y axis

Tags: r, plot

Using `plot.survfit`, I want to plot 4 KM survival curve event plots `(fun='event')` with the same y-axis. I know with the survival plot you can specify a `ymin value`, but it seems there is no work around when plotting the events.  Any suggestions would be appreciated. Current code:

```
plot(fit.1, fun="event", mark.time=F, col=c(1,2), lty=1, yscale=100)

plot(fit.2, fun="event", mark.time=F, col=c(1,2), lty=1, yscale=100)

plot(fit.3, fun="event", mark.time=F, col=c(1,2), lty=1, yscale=100)

plot(fit.5, fun="event", conf.int=F, mark.time=F, col=c(1), yscale=100)  

lines(fit.4, fun="event", col=2, lty=1, mark.time=F, conf.int=F)
```

Comment: What exactl is your question? And it's hard to help you without having data/a reproducible example.

Comment: How do I change the yaxis in the plots with the event function?  I know you can change the yaxis with the survival function - ymin=.75 as example, but don't see any options for a ymax (also get an error when specifying ymax).